# How to color and add styling to my types in VSCode when programming Dart

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

I want to change the colour of my declared types (and possibly add bold, italics and other styling) in VSCode when programming in Dart.  Is this possible?  I think it would aid readability.

For example, I would like Widget, BuildContext and Loading Container to be in a different colour (maybe a grey). The keywords are in currently in blue.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LoadingContainer(
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, you can download other color themes from the [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Themes&sortBy=Downloads) that have better highlighting support for Flutter/Dart than the default ones.

Comment: I'm quite colour blind so defining my own suits me best...the below solution works well though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To select a different theme select `ctrl + shft + p` type 'color theme' then choose one.  You can also install new themes from the marketplace by typing 'theme' in the extensions:marketplace search bar

**For more finite control**...in your user settings file for the selected color theme add the following

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Visual Studio Light]": {
        "types": "#aaaaaa",
        "comments": "#00dd00",
        "functions": "#f00",
```

...can also define italics, bold and underlined too

```
    "variables": "#f00",
    "strings": "#FF5555",
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "keyword",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic ",
            }
        },
```

Comment: What you probably want is the 'Dark+ (default dark)' theme in vs code. Go to themes by using Ctrl + K, Ctrl + T and then choose what you want.