# Change the colour of the '[Dart] The value of the field '_lectures' isn't used' warning

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

I have found a number of options to change colours here
[How to color and add styling to my types in VSCode when programming Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102414/how-to-color-and-add-styling-to-my-types-in-vscode-when-programming-dart/50103196#50103196)
but I can't find a setting to change the green underline for the

```
'[Dart] The value of the field '_lectures' isn't used'
```

warning.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*(I'm green / red colour blind so I can't tell the difference as easily as most between a red and a green underline...plus my monitor is a little unique!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colours used in the squiggles come from the VS Code theme rather than the Dart Code plugin, so you should be able to change them with `workbench.colorCustomizations` in your user settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorInfo.foreground": "#FFAA00"
}
```

More info on these is available here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

Comment: That's great, many thanks (nice reference guide for that too)